# Accessing MVC4's detault Membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Working with a MVC4 project as provided by the MVC4 Beta release - the updated templates - I find the webconfig's DefaultMembershipProvider offers a MinRequiredPasswordLength setting. The Register view is rendering '@Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength'. But when I change the value in webconfig it doesn't change the value rendered by the view. Why not?

thx

Answer (score 0):

> Why not?

Weird, it does change for me. For example I set it to 25 in the web.cnofig:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add 
            name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
            connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="25" 
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            applicationName="/" 
        />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

and I git the expected result on the Register page:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's pulling the value from machineConfig and not paying any attention to the project's web.config. Does that ring any bells for you? I've had other framework-related weirdness - e.g. i can't get webadmin to find my db. I suppose i could run a repair against VS and or the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same behavior, setting the defaultProvider in web.config did the trick for me.

Before:

```
<membership>
```

After:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
```

Now when I change the settings in web.config they are reflected on the register page.

[EDIT]

There is definitely more going on here. I updated VS & .Net and now things have gone back to normal. I believe the membership provider was trying to use both web.config and another hidden config file. If you experience this problem I'd recommend updating to the latest version of everything as this was likely a bug in the MVC4 beta.